# xpath to retrieve list of objects by node

Tags: java, xpath

How to retrieve Psinfo object with individual attribute values  using Xpath by Gender from below xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Employees>
    <Employee>
        <Psinfo>
            <Name>Jhon</Name>
            <Gender xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string"
                >Male</Gender>
            <Empsal xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string"
                >95572553</Empsal>
        </Psinfo>
        <Psinfo>
            <Name>David</Name>
            <Gender xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string"
                >Male</Gender>
            <Empsal xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string"
                >1000000</Empsal>
        </Psinfo>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

I tried with xpath using this expression:

```
/Employees/Employee/Psinfo[contains(Gender,'Male')]
```

and the following Java code:

```
     final NodeList list = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
                        final Node node1 = list.item(i);
                        // System.out.println(node.getNodeName().getTextContent());
final String result1 = (String) expr.evaluate(node1, XPathConstants.STRING); 
//but instead of getting individual tag values, giving whole  value as "JhonMale95572553
                    }
```

I am expecting for each Iteration there is one attribute value

```
Jhon
Male
95572553
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this XPath Expression:

```
//Psinfo[contains(Gender,'Male')]
```

Comment: trying to get results by :  final String result1 = (String) expr.evaluate(node1, XPathConstants.STRING); but instead of getting individual tag values, I am getting value as "JhonMale95572553"

Answer (score 0):

There is no element named `S36B` in your XML therefore the result is empty.

EDIT after you corrected your XPath expression:

The expression string is correct. Therefore there must be an error in the code which you did not show us (e.g. how you construct the document, how you build the XPath expression object, etc.).

Comment: trying to get results by : final String result1 = (String) expr.evaluate(node1, XPathConstants.STRING); but instead of getting individual tag values, I am getting value as "JhonMale95572553"

Comment: @wero Code Review is not for debugging. Questions are only on topic there if they are working as intended.

Comment: Question was updated , Not able to retrieve Individual values .